# Javascript lastIndexOf Trailing URL

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if the `lastIndexOf` of a URL does NOT contain `/index.htm` or `/index.html` as shown here:

- Alert: www.example.com/this/is/a/test/
- Alert: www.example.com/this/is/a/test

No alert on these scenarios:

- www.example.com/this/is/a/test/index.htm
- www.example.com/this/is/a/test/index.html
- www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.htm
- www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.html
- www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.php
- www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.whatever

I thought this could do it, but it's always firing:

```
var url = "www.example.com/this/is/a/test/index.htm";
var path = window.location.pathname;

var path = url.split('/').slice(-2).join('/');
if(!path.lastIndexOf('.htm') >= 0){
   alert(path+' .htm is missing')
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/un11awLx/1/

Comment: `!path.lastIndexOf('.htm') >= 0` makes no sense Why are you not just checking for `-1`?

Comment: You're converting the result of `.lastIndexOf` to a boolean then checking to see if it's `>= 0`, which is always `true`.

Comment: And why the `.split("/").slice(-2).join("/")`? Seems pointless and probably far more expensive.

Comment: ... Why wouldn't you just check for `< 0`? In any case, operator precedence matters.

Comment: And under your *"no alert for these scenarios"*, the first two *do* have `.index.htm` or `index.html` and the rest do not, so why are they grouped together?

Comment: Don't change the code in the question like that. Now the answers below make no sense.

Comment: Evan, please: take a few moments. Could you re-phrase your question to make it more comprehensible? I *think* you want to trigger an `alert()` if the URL ends in either `index.html` or `index.htm`? But your list of URLs, [as noted earlier by squint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434780/javascript-lastindexof-trailing-url#comment47039049_29434780), contains two URLs that apparently *should* trigger the `alert()`, which makes your question extraordinarily difficult to answer because of the (apparent) inconsistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't implementing it correctly. Here are two better solutions:

```
var url = "www.example.com/this/is/a/test/index.html";
var path = window.location.pathname;

var paths = url.split('/');
var lastItem = paths[paths.length-1];
/* Solution 1 */
if(lastItem.indexOf('.htm') < 0){
   alert(path+' .htm is missing')
}
/* Solution 2 */
if(url.indexOf('.htm')<0){
     alert('missing .htm');   
}
```

Comment: This solves the challenge when .htm, .html is missing, etc. However, should the URL be like downloadme.zip it still fires, because its looking for .htm, etc. Can we have it ignore other extensions, too?

Comment: In solution 1, you can change it to if(lastItem.indexOf('.')<0). This will check if there is a period in the last item of url.

Comment: yes. checking for the '.' comment was very helpful and thank u for cleaning up my poor attempt. i can now inject the index.htm into something else now that i know how to check for it.

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer, I'd suggest changing your code to either the following (assuming the use of modern browsers):

```
// creating a named function,
// haystack: String, the string we're looking at,
// needles: Array, containing the strings you want to see
//          if the haystack ends with:
function endsIn(haystack, needles) {
  // using Array.prototype.some() to see if some/any
  // of the needles are found in the haystack, returning true
  // if the assessment within the function returns at least one
  // true/truthy value:
  return needles.some(function(needle) {
    // using String.prototype.endsWith() to see if the supplied
    // string (needle) is found in the haystack string,
    // endsWith() returns a Boolean true if the haystack does 
    // end with the needle, false otherwise:
    return haystack.endsWith(needle);
  });
}

// creating an array of the <li> elements, using Array.prototype.slice()
// and Function.prototype.call(), along with document.querySelectorAll()
// to retrieve the nodeList of <li> elements to be converted to an array:
var listItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('li'), 0);

// iterating over that array of <li> elements:
listItems.forEach(function(li) {
  // the first argument to the anonymous function (here 'li', but the
  // name is irrelevant) is the array-element over which we're iterating.

  // here we set the borderColor to green (if the text of the <li> does
  // end with either 'index.htm' or 'index.html', so the function returns
  // true) or to red if the string does not end in those strings (and the
  // function returns false):
  li.style.borderColor = endsIn(li.textContent, ['index.htm', 'index.html']) ? 'green' : 'red';
  // logging the text to the console, and an appropriate message
  // (based on an imperfect understanding of your question), rather than
  // multiple alerts (which are just annoying, diagnostically):
  console.log(li.textContent, " - ", endsIn(li.textContent, ['index.htm', 'index.html']) ? "Well done!" : "Where's the 'index.html'?");
});
```

```js
function endsIn(haystack, needles) {
  return needles.some(function(needle) {
    return haystack.endsWith(needle);
  });
}

var listItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('li'), 0);

listItems.forEach(function(li) {
  li.style.borderColor = endsIn(li.textContent, ['index.htm', 'index.html']) ? 'green' : 'red';
  console.log(li.textContent, " - ", endsIn(li.textContent, ['index.htm', 'index.html']) ? "Well done!" : "Where's the 'index.html'?");
});
```

```css
li {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>www.example.com/this/is/a/test/index.htm</li>
  <li>www.example.com/this/is/a/test/index.html</li>
  <li>www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.htm</li>
  <li>www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.html</li>
  <li>www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.php</li>
  <li>www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.whatever</li>
</ol>
```

Or, using a regular-expression approach (which is a little more verbose, but potentially more useful cross-browser):

```
function endsIn(haystack, needles) {
  // initialising an (empty) array:
  var regexes = [];
  // iterating over the array of needles:
  needles.forEach(function(needle) {
    // creating regular expressions from the needles, after escaping
    // potential regular-expression special characters (such as the
    // period included in the string 'index.html'), and appending the
    // '$' (to search that the string ends with that string):
    regexes.push(new RegExp(needle.replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&") + '$', 'i'));
  });

  // iterating over the array of regular expressions:
  return regexes.some(function(reg) {
    // again, the first argument (here: 'reg') is the array-element,
    // and we're using RegExp.prototype.test() (which returns a
    // Boolean true if the supplied string (haystack) matches
    // the regular expression):
    return reg.test(haystack);
  });

}

var listItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('li'), 0);

listItems.forEach(function(li) {
  li.style.borderColor = endsIn(li.textContent, ['index.htm', 'index.html']) ? 'green' : 'red';
  console.log(li.textContent, " - ", endsIn(li.textContent, ['index.htm', 'index.html']) ? "Well done!" : "Where's the 'index.html'?");
});
```

```js
function endsIn(haystack, needles) {
  var regexes = [];
  needles.forEach(function(needle) {
    regexes.push(new RegExp(needle.replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&") + '$', 'i'));
  });

  return regexes.some(function(reg) {
    return reg.test(haystack);
  });

}

var listItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('li'), 0);

listItems.forEach(function(li) {
  li.style.borderColor = endsIn(li.textContent, ['index.htm', 'index.html']) ? 'green' : 'red';
  console.log(li.textContent, " - ", endsIn(li.textContent, ['index.htm', 'index.html']) ? "Well done!" : "Where's the 'index.html'?");
});
```

```css
li {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>www.example.com/this/is/a/test/index.htm</li>
  <li>www.example.com/this/is/a/test/index.html</li>
  <li>www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.htm</li>
  <li>www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.html</li>
  <li>www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.php</li>
  <li>www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.whatever</li>
</ol>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`new RegExp()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).
- [`String.prototype.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)<sup>[compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith#Browser_compatibility)</sup>.
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
if(!path.lastIndexOf('.htm') >= 0)
```

To

```
if(!(path.lastIndexOf('.htm') >= 0))
```

It fires every time because js engine firstly calculate !path.lastIndexOf('.htm') and then compares result with 0

For example index of .htm is 10

First calculation is !10 and it gives false as result (here is !10 casts to bool)

Second operation: false >= 0 (false casts to 0 and condition is true)

Comment: Personally I find this harder to read than flipping the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your code how it is, just add some parentheses:

```
if(! (path.lastIndexOf('.htm') >= 0) ){
   alert(path+' .htm is missing')
}
```

In your current example, if you substitute the actual values, you will see what's going on. You end up with something like this:

```
if( ! 10 >= 0 )

if( false >= 0 )

if( true )
```

Adding the parentheses will give you the expected result:

```
if( ! ( 10 >= 0 ) )

if( ! ( true )

if( false )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a regular expression instead of `indexOf`. Otherwise, you'd need to list out all the possible file extensions.

```js
var strings = [
  "www.example.com/this/is/a/test/",
  "www.example.com/this/is/a/test",
  "www.example.com/this/is/a/test/index.htm",
  "www.example.com/this/is/a/test/index.html",
  "www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.htm",
  "www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.html",
  "www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.php",
  "www.example.com/this/is/a/test/helloworld.whatever"
]
// Ends with .xxxxxxxxxxxx
var regex = /\.[a-zA-Z]+$/;

for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {

  console.log(strings[i], regex.test(strings[i]))
}
```